# Using JQuery DatePicker in Wordpress backend

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I'm trying to add a datepicker to the wordpress backend. Tried initially using simply input type="date" and it worked fine in everything except safari which apparently hasn't implemented that input type (or so I've read) So... I decided to use JQuery datepicker but so far it appears that the widget returns different format in different browsers.

Here is my relevant code:

The input field

```
<input type="text" id="new_date" name="new_date"  class="input" defaultValue="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" >
```

with the javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#new_date").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

I have loaded WP Datepicker and activated it and placed #new_date in the settings, told it to use WP Datepicker in the backend and added yy-mm-dd in the date format text box on the bottom.

It appears to work just fine in Chrome and Edge clicking on November 4, 2020 from the Datepicker return 2020-11-04 as expected but here is where it gets interesting.
Clicking on the same date in Firefox and Opera returns: 11/04/2020
I don't have A Mac so I'm not sure about Safari.

hmmmm?

Comment: In your case, problem is a formatting date ?

Comment: Yes. It appears that the return from the datepicker is formatted differently depending on which browser  it is running on. It makes sense that Chome and Edge would be similar since they both use the same engine now. Buy why, using the same code would clicking on the datepicker calendar return differently formatted date in the text input box?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use a `dateFormat` option like this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( 
    "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" // You can change yy-mm-dd of you need
);
```

**This Example `DatePicker` from jQuery**

```js
 $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#format" ).change(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( 
      "option", "dateFormat",$(this ).val());
    });
 });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Format date</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="30"></p>
 
<p>Format options:<br>
  <select id="format">
    <option value="mm/dd/yy">Default - mm/dd/yy</option>
    <option value="yy-mm-dd">ISO 8601 - yy-mm-dd</option>
    <option value="d M, y">Short - d M, y</option>
    <option value="d MM, y">Medium - d MM, y</option>
    <option value="DD, d MM, yy">Full - DD, d MM, yy</option>
    <option value="&apos;day&apos; d &apos;of&apos; MM &apos;in the year&apos; yy">With text - 'day' d 'of' MM 'in the year' yy</option>
  </select>
</p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```